# My website is slow only when connecting from certain IP addresses

Tags: networking, router, connection, webserver, apache-http-server

I am running an apache server on debian stable from my house. My ISP is AT&T, and my servere is ethernet connected to the gigabit router / fiber modem (Motorala NVG589) that AT&T installed with my Gigapower service. I am using the NVG589's builtin "Apache" setting for NAT routing to forward unsolicited :80/:443 traffic to my server. I've tried virtually every router setting I can find, including turning off all firewall features, as well as using IP passthrough, and the problems were the same:

If I try to connect to the website using my domain name or public IP address from any of the other devices in my lan, or my phone using Verizon 4G (i.e. a device not in my lan), my website loads dreadfully slow. It appears to download either exactly 46kB or 92kB exactly every two minutes. I have tested in chrome and firefox on each of Windows 7, Windows 8.1, debian stable, and debian testing, all of which exhibit the same behavior.

However, if I connect to localhost from the device itself, or if I connect to the device's local address (192.168.1.xx) from another machine on the network, the site loads instantly. Additionally, I have tried connecting to it from many different IP addresses using tor, and in all these cases the site loads instantly.

The traceroute to my site looks like

```
traceroute to www.mydomain.com (my.public.ip.addr) 30 hops max, 60 byte packet
1  my-public-ip-addr.lightspeed.austtx.sbcglobal.net (my.public.ip.addr)  0.890 ms  1.130 ms  1.398 ms
```

and pinging the site looks like

```
PING www.mydomain.com (my.public.ip.addr) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from my-public-ip-addr.lightspeed.austtx.sbcglobal.net (my.public.ip.addr): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.654 ms
[similar ...]
```

If I do a `ping -s 64000 www.mydomain.com` from a lan computer, the site still appears to be responsive even though this appears to break the 46/92kB per 2 minutes phenomenon when connecting via browser.

I called AT&T and the representative admitted to observing the problem firsthand by visiting my website. After all his tests came back inconclusive, he said the problem was with AT&T's  upstream internet provider (I thought they were their own ISP?) and that he would email them for me. It has been over two weeks and I haven't receive any response.

Does anyone have any ideas to help me troubleshoot this problem? If it were only my lan that couldn't connect, I would point to the router and say it is just doing a poor job at NAT routing, but since the problem exists when I connect from my phone's 4G connection (Wifi off) it can't be solely a lan problem. It's like connections from certain IP addresses are being blocked.

Comment: My website is extremely low traffic (I am probably the only person to use it at all) and I'm on a gigabit connection. The fact that the symptoms are only exhibited from certain IP addresses, independent of time of day / day of week make it seem like they would have to be doing it on purpose (actively killing connections to my website if the IP address is geographically near mine) if that were the case.

Comment: As my post indicates, I tested connections from MANY IP addresses through tor, and in all the cases except from my lan and my phone the connection was fast.

Comment: I was going direct you down a specific troubleshooting path but forget it

Comment: @Ramhound **please be polite**. This user seems to have made a reasonable attempt to fix their problem and promptly answered your queries for more details.

Comment: @nullUser it sounds like you may need to give AT&T a call again. I doubt there's much you can do about it. Have you checked that there isn't some kind of QOS on your router that's causing it to slow down?

Comment: @nhinkle I just checked again and there is no QOS on my router (that is under my control).

Answer (score 0):

@nullUser, I'm having the same exact problem and the only solution I found was to go to Ip Passthrough under the firewall tab and set "Allocation Mode" to "Passthrough", "Default Server Internal Address" set to you lan address, "Passthrough Mode" set to "DHCPS-Fixed" but in doing so there is no LAN access.

UPDATE: Site is not accessible from outside.